# Ordered List Vertical in IE, Horizontal elsewhere

Tags: html, css

Hopefully this is something simple I am missing, I have an OL encompassing a set of LI links.
In Chrome and firefox this works perfectly, in IE8 they appear as a numbered list moving vertically down the page.

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <img src="images/header.png" alt="Logo">
    <ol>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html">page2</a></li>
    <li><a href="page3.html">page3</a></li>
    <li><a href="page4.html">page4</a></li>
    <li><a href="page5.html">page5</a></li>
    <li><a href="page6.html">page6</a></li>
    <li><a href="page7.html">page7</a></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

CSS;

```
.header {
   width:888px;
   height:119px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-top: 20px;
   padding:0;
   text-align: left;
}
.header ol {
   margin-top: -32px;
   width: 888px;
   padding:0;
   margin-left: 10px;
}
.header li {
     font-weight: bold;
     display: inline;
     padding-right: 20px;
     padding-left: 20px;
     border-right: solid 1px;
     border-right-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Is there something basic I am missing here? Doing some searching doesn't seem to provide me with a solution. There are some suggestions of using `display: inline;` on the LI but this doesn't appear to make any difference.
The behaviour I am looking for is horizontal ordering of the links as displayed in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Could you say in the question whether you wanted the list-items to be laid out horizontally or vertically?

Comment: Heh, managed to write a whole question without even explicitly saying. Jason has managed to find my problem but I'll update it for future reference.

Comment: \o/, will be handy for others :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE8 and lower versions of IE have trouble implementing `display:inline` on many block-level elements.

You could try to `float` the `li`s...

so remove the `display:inline` and replace with something like `float:left`

Comment: Thanks. This worked after some other changes. For some reason I had the height defined in the body class.

Comment: @JasonGennaro, One other slight problem, firefox now shows the numbers for the ordered list?

Comment: Try adding `list-style: none;` to your `.header ol` selector.